# PhoneRTC demo application

Tags: node.js, cordova, phonertc

I am Trying to get PhoneRTC demo up and running.
https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc/

I actually have a bunch of doubts

First of all, my understanding:
1. We need a TURN server
2. We need a signaling Server (demo/server in repo)
3. We need a cordova project which will use phoneRTC project (demo/client in repo)

1. started AWS instance, assigned a dynamic DNS.
   installed TURN server and started it - but now I'm confused over private ip and public ip part mentioned in tutorial as my ip changes every time I restart the instance. I have one dns name (from noip) which will stick to it. So I'm exploring on how to set TURN server with that
2. I checked out the source code and followed the npm install cordva etc steps,
3. For Signaling server, I navigated to demo/server in the source code and tried node index.js after npm install, but got several errors regarding the module not found.
4. demo/client is also a nodeJS project, right ? If i get it up and running, that is the video chat, right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon provides [Elastic IPs](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1346) which allow you to make permanent IP addresses for your EC2 hosts.

Here are the full commands required to run the demo from scratch:

```
# install global dependencies
npm install -g cordova bower grunt-cli

# clone phonertc
git clone https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc.git

# build client
cd demo/client
npm install
bower install

cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console
cordova plugin add https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc.git

# follow the instructions for iOS after running this command
cordova platform add ios android  

# before running the next command, make sure to
# change your server details in demo/client/app/scripts/signaling.js 
# and in demo/client/app/scripts/CallCtrl.js 
grunt build --force

# build server
cd ../server
npm install
```

To run the server:

```
cd demo/server
node index.js
```

To run the client on Android:

```
cordova run android
```

To run the client on iOS run:

```
cordova build ios
```

And run the project from Xcode on a real iOS device.

Comment: does running 2 devices on same ip could cause problems with the TURN?

Comment: When I run `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device` from `demo/client`, I see a `Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.`. Am I missing something here? Isn't the demo client already a `Cordova` project?

Comment: @Neo I run into the same error... How did you solve? We are running Cordova 4.0 CLI

Comment: I actually faced the same issue, and as I was running out for time,  I moved on to weemo/sightcall for the time being even though it is paid. But I'm quite interested in using phonertc for my needs.

Comment: @Napster I got the demo running on Android. Trying IOS now. I answered your question with my steps

Comment: @neo I solved that problem by running `grunt cordova` once before `cordova plugin add`

Answer (score 4):

I got the demo up and running, doing the next steps (Android), with ionic CLI:

```
# install global dependencies
npm install -g cordova bower grunt-cli

# Get a GIT clone, needed for copying files
git clone https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc.git

# start new ionic project
ionic create phonertc-ionic
cd phonertc

# Copy files from GIT clone to your ionic project
cp -R phonertc-gitclone\demo\client\* phonertc-ionic\

# install dependencies
npm install
bower install

# install plugins
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console
cordova plugin add https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc.git

# add android platform
cordova platform add android

# install/running signaling server
cd phonertc-gitclone/demo/server
npm install
node index.js

# setting up turn server (not sure if needed)
# I installed it on a VirtualBox Ubuntu server, also see:
# https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc/wiki/Installation
# Next ports should be open to your Ubuntu TURN server:
# TCP 443
# TCP 3478-3479
# TCP 32355-65535
# UDP 3478-3479
# UDP 32355-65535
sudo apt-get install rfc5766-turn-server
# Edit /etc/turnserver.conf and change:
listening-ip=<internal IP VirtualBox Ubuntu>
relay-ip=<internal IP VirtualBox Ubuntu>
external-ip=<internal IP VirtualBox Ubuntu>
min-port=32355 
max-port=65535
realm=<your domain>
# Also uncomment
lt-cred-mech
fingerprint
# Edit /etc/turnuserdb.conf and at the end, add:
username:password
# Start TURN server
sudo /etc/init.d/rfc5766-turn-server start

# before running the next command, make sure to
# change your server details in demo/client/app/scripts/signaling.js 
# and in demo/client/app/scripts/CallCtrl.js 
cd phonertc-ionic/
grunt build --force

# Copy files from phonertc-ionic app dir to www dir
cp -R phonertc-ionic/app/* phonertc-ionic/www/

# Build and run to android
ionic run android
```

**NOTE:**

Fill phonertc-ionic and phonertc-gitclone dirs with yours.
At this moment I can only test between 2 Android devices. Sound is crap at the moment, but video is great.
Trying to build on IOS now.

Comment: I get a splash screen showing the Cordova logo and then a blank screen showing nothing.

Comment: Ok so the problem was because I was running it on the browser. The demo app will only work phone to phone.